# Android: How can I display a google map in an android app?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have built an app that does some co-ordinate calculation for me. It works well it retrieves points from a database I built as well.  What I want to do now is when a menu button is pressed display a map.  I did a tutorial that is simply a map display.. that's all it does when it runs.  but when I try to incorporate what I have done in my app..I have no luck at all.

So here are some of the items I have done and maybe someone can help me.

Here are the important lines from my android manifest.xml

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Here is the the XML for the map display activity

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0EVD3Q_WMbtaa_vIjrPoaiN7Egbs8amSorNF-qw"
        />
```

I have a menu item in my main application that I want to invoke the map( I want to pass coordinates too it later.. but right now if it would just simply display I would be happy) In this code it is the case statement 3 that I am trying to invoke the map.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {   

            switch (item.getItemId()) {   
            case 1: 
                String v_band1 = spin2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                 Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(Tower.this, BuildList.class);
                 myIntent2.putExtra("BAND", v_band1);
                 Tower.this.startActivity(myIntent2);
                return true;  
            case 2:
                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(Tower.this, Activity2.class);
                 Tower.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                 return true; 
            case 3:
                Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(Tower.this, Mapit.class);
                Tower.this.startActivity(myIntent1);
                return true; 
            case 4:
                loadspinner();
                return true; 

            }   
            return false;   
        }
```

in the test app there is an import line at the top of the class

```
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
```

In my new app when you start typing in the import statement you get to "import com.google.android.maps." and the MapActivity or anything will not come up to select as it did in the test tutorial.  What am I doing wrong??  I have tried  pasted my entire Android Manfiest.xml asa well as the XML from the view to display the map, in here but the whole thing does not show up. So I added the googlemaps line to show you I use it.

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="true"/>
```

Comment: Make sure the target of your app is one that includes the Google Maps libraries. Usually, the ones that contains "Google Inc." string in their name.

Comment: But what's going on? Any logs, exceptions from logcat?

Answer (score 0):

What SDK are you building for? The functions you're attempting to use are only available in 1.5 or higher.

Comment: Im using Eclipse and 2.1. SDK I am new to this so its a slow process.  I an not sure how to do the loggin to see the errors, that woudl be a help for sure, I tried to do debuggin or look to do debuggin like i do  in Visual studio where you can go line by line to see where it bombs and what variables are.  Also i was frustrated at not being able to paste my whole manifext.xml in here as well.. i coudl edit and edit and the origianl was there but what is displayed for question is only part of what i pasted.